# Webmin doesn't work fine behind reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have Webmin configured to listen on localhost:1000 and nginx configured to listen on my.domain.tld:80  with reverse proxy pointing to Webmin. This configuration works fine but sometimes I get 404 errors and HTTP headers say that this is Webmin's miniserv puts 302 redirects into them:

HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Sun, 3 Jan 2010 11:38:46 GMT
Server: MiniServ/0.01
Connection: close
Location: http://my.domain.tld:10000/webmin/

Can you advice on how to disable this behavior?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @HopelessN00b - I disagree. I would argue that Webmin is not a "service provider's management interface". It is an independent free, open source project that is an administration tool which can be installed on a server for "administering, monitoring, or automating [the hardware or software of servers]" (see points 1 & 2 of on-topic subjects). IMO It's sister software "virtualmin" is more of an open source alternative to cPanel so would be closer to what you are suggesting...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a very similar problem.  However, my problem was specifically that after you login to Webmin, it would redirect to the non-proxied address and port.

To further illustrate, assume I wanted webmin to appear to the outside post-proxy on 'https://example.com/admin/webmin', but it's really running on 'https://example.com:10000'.  Going to the first address would display the login page, but redirect me to the second address (302 Moved Permanently).  I could then type or paste the first address, and all would work as though I was logged in.

I tried following the directions on the Webmin wiki, your suggestion above, and various other suggestions.  Then I found the solution.  I needed to add another ProxyReversePass to my Apache configuration, to catch the URL in the redirect.

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
SSLProxyEngine On

ProxyPass /admin/webmin/ https://example.com:10000/
ProxyHTMLURLMap https://localhost:10000 /admin/webmin

<Location /admin/webmin/>
 ProxyHTMLExtended On
 SetOutputFilter proxy-html
 ProxyPassReverse https://localhost:10000/
 ProxyPassReverse https://example.com:10000/
</Location>
```

Of course, in /etc/webmin/config I have webprefix="/admin/webmin" and webprefixnoredir=1.  I wanted SSL protection over my local LAN, so I left it SSL enabled and did the SSL proxy thing.  Hope this helps as a possible solution to anyone experiencing this issue.

I was so desperate I was trying to modify miniserv.pl and even thought about breaking out mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out myself. When you configure Webmin to bind to localhost only you should use the following command in miniserv.conf:

sockets=127.0.0.1:10000

This is insted of host=localhost and port=1000. I hope it will help someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the **sockets** option *almost* got me there, but I’m using SSL on the front end (which handles certificates better) and I’m coming in on a different port on the front end, so I also needed to add:

```
proxy_redirect http://www.example.com:10000 https://www.example.com:10443;
```